# MySQL Newbie - Select all False in One to Many

Tags: mysql

```
Devices             Network_Card
==================  ===========================================
| id | hostname  |  | id | device_id | ip_address | dns       |
==================  ===========================================
| 1  | desktop1  |  | 1  | 1         | 10.0.0.1   | desktop1  |
| 2  | laptop1   |  | 2  | 2         | 10.0.0.2   | laptop1   |
| 3  | laptop2   |  | 3  | 2         | 10.0.0.3   | laptop1w  |
| 4  | desktop2  |  | 4  | 3         | 10.0.0.4   | george    | 
| .. | ...       |  | 5  | 4         | 10.0.0.5   | desktop2w |
==================  ===========================================
```

Hi folks, here's my situation. We have a home grown computer inventory with 500+ devices and the db gets populated from different sources. I'm trying to find the discrepancies in this case, so I'm trying to select devices.id where *I don't have a DNS record is NOT LIKE the hostname*. In this case, it would return devices.id = 3

I haven't done relational db queries in a long time, and my brain can't process the double negatives, so any help would be great.

Comment: Wouldn't it also return `4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query might do it for you:

```
select d.id, d.hostname, n.dns
from devices d
    left join network_card n on d.id = n.device_id
where d.hostname != substring(n.dns, 1, LENGTH(d.hostname))
```

I'm using substring since I'm not sure how to do a field + wildcard to use within a NOT LIKE expression.  Using substring lets you do a straight != comparison.

**Update:** Thanks to PaparazzoKid for the sqlfiddle at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a260/1

Comment: The `0` in your `SUBSTRING` should be a `1`.  From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring: `the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1`

Comment: @RocketHazmat - fixed in answer -- thanks! gets me every time.

Comment: Works as it should. Here's a fiddle if you want to add it to the answer: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a260/1

Comment: Yes, this certainly did it... took me a bit to accomodate the query to my real db but it looks like it works! Thanks